# Why say Visual Studio 2012 not good than Visual Studio 2013

Tags: database, cloud

I am using Visual Studio 2012 for developing C# destop applications and Asp.Net web applications.But my friends using Visual Studio 2013 for their developing purpose.
they said visual Studio 2013 better than 2012, But I working without any issue in 2012.

- Is it true visual studio 2013 better than 2012?
- If it is **No** Why microsoft launch Visual Studio 2013 within one year?

Thank you.

Comment: This is an opiniated question... __And such questions are not allowed on StackOverflow!__

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it invites opinion, but Microsoft is famous for launching products and then relaunching something else shortly thereafter.  Just look at the history of Windows.